# Block level link HTML5 article

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I was asking if the following is possible. I have a HTML5 article tag, with inside that a figure and figcaption tags. The caption is overlapping the image. The figure should be clickable, but I want some other links in the caption that linked to another page, like a categorie page.

How should my markup looks like.
Now I have the following, but than the a first a tag will be immediately closed after it's opening the a tag.

```
                <li class="grid_12 blog-post">
            <a href="#">
                <figure class="post-thumb">
                    <img src="images/blog-thumb.png" alt="Post thumbnail">

                    <figcaption class="entry-post"> 
                        <span class="capitalize">Entry</span>

                        <h1 class="entry-title">
                            <a href="#" title="">Fris. Responsive. Retina Ready.</a>
                        </h1><!-- End h1 .entry-title -->

                        <ul class="entry-meta">                   
                            <li class="author">
                                By <a href="#">Casper Biemans</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="published">
                                On <a href="#">September 1, 2012</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="entry-categories">
                                In <a href="#">Digital Art</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="comment-count">
                                With <a href="#">22 Comments</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="permalink">
                                <img src="images/permalink_icon.png" alt="Permalink post"><a href="#">Permalink</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul><!-- End ul.entry-meta -->
                    </figcaption><!-- End figcaption.entry-post -->
                </figure><!-- End figure.post-thumb -->
            </a>
            </li><!-- End li.grid_12 blog-post -->
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it anyway as it is probably no valid markup. Couldn't you set the link inside the container and give it maybe position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; and position: relative to the parent??

Comment: Yes, links should never be nested. Is the image positioned behind the text, with all of the image being clickable but some of the texts on it leading to different pages than the image itself? If so, then maybe an image map would be a solution.